# Difference between linux commands

Tags: linux, command-line

Does anyone know the difference between these commands ?

- who & ps & ls -l
- who; ps; ls -l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line will cause each command to be run asynchronously. Each command will be run in the background in its own subshell.

The second one will have them run sequentially in order.

Comment: So you mean all the commands in the second case will be run at the same time ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

"&" is used to command run in the background, so it means that command who, ps and ls -l the shell will executes the command by command in the background in a subshell.

On the other hand ";" is a command separator, it's like pressing the ENTER key to execute a command, so the commands will run one by one in the shell.